# Recurring direct payment

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to adding recurring payments to my application.

The requirement is as follows:

1.) User should be able to enter his/her credit card number, cvc and expirary in my application.
2.) I will submit the details along with his/her recurring payment option eg: 3 months, 6months etc
3.) Should receive response stating the recurring payments successful.

I went through the [API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/#id08669F0705Z) but it didn't help.

I basically want to create a paypal direct recurring payment application (using C#). Any link or sample code to begin with is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really sure there's much to suggest beyond what's documented on the Paypal site. What wasn't helpful about it?

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation you require is [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)

Most Paypal recurring transactions users implement a hosted page checkout, and i have not witnessed a single api checkout implementation. Do get in touch with Paypal as your page need to match up to certain requirements before you can collect credit card information on your webpage